# Allow our own systems to use an API and restrict it from the general internet without using authentication

Tags: apache, authentication, api, access-control

I have an Apache server which is reverse proxy'd to some Java container. In Java container there is an API that we don't want internet to see but expect our own systems to use it without any authentication.

Is it possible to achieve it in Apache server?

Comment: Why the requirement not to use auth?  It is usually easy to add at least basic authentication.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, well the other systems that uses our api are legacy and they send a token(which they use to send to a previous system than ours) which is not valid for our application.